# Restart an application if taking lot of memory

Tags: process

How can I restart an application if it's taking a lot of say CPU utilization or taking too much RAM on Linux, is there any shell script to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to use a script to do that? Close the application. Or, in the system monitor, end or kill the process. If you don't want to use the GUI, then you can open a terminal, run `ps ax` to find the process ID and use `kill prosessid` to end it. Use the -9 switch to use force, but avoid that whenever possible.

Comment: dont want it to be manual, need some automated stuff.

Comment: I don't think anything like that exists. For CPU, you can renice it so that all other applications will be prioritized. For RAM.. What if you decide to record a screencast. Should the system just prevent you from doing that? Or if you want to start 3D animations? Having the system automatically deny you the opportunity to do what you want, seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Jo-Erend Schinstad - actually need this for a server that has multiple applications running on it, and it happends quite many times that one of the many application start taking full utilisation and has to be restarted ...